# how to get information about network adapter physical in c++

Tags: c++

I get information about All network adapter installed on my computer with function GetNetworkParam, [GetInterfaceInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365947(v=vs.85).aspx) and etc...

**now in C++, I want get information physical network adapter in my system not all adapter(not VMWare, and etc), just physical, how do it?**

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?  What sorts of data do the APIs you've listed tell you about the interfaces?  For example, do any of them tell you the PCI bus location?

Comment: I regret to inform you that in the 1400+ pages that make up the C++ standard, there's no mention of anything called a "network adapter". Furthermore, there is no universal API to obtain this information that works on every operating system in the world. If you don't even realize the basic, elementary, fundamental fact that you need to specify which operating system you're using, when asking this kind of a question, then whatever you're trying to do, you won't be able to do it. Just keep learning basic C++ for a few more years, or so, and try again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please bear with the ruthless people who inhabit this strange world!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I 'am curious to know there is no such a direct feature in cpp?

Comment: Not until standard C++ gets a decent network library.

Answer (score 1):

As Sam V. Pointed out, C++ is a language that knows nothing about network hardware. However there are many ways in which you can find that information, usually by using some libraries or frameworks. It depends however on some of your requirements. For example, finding a completely portable solution is probably going to be hard.

That said, I would use **Qt** for this, as it is portable over many popular platforms while still containing an [impressive list of features](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html). Check out the following from the official documentation:

- [Bearer Management](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/bearer-management.html)
- [QNetworkSession](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworksession.html)
- [QNetworkConfiguration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkconfiguration.html)
- [QNetworkInterface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html)

Some example code I use to filter interfaces in my application:

```
 QList<QNetworkInterface> interfaceList=QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
    for(QNetworkInterface iface:interfaceList){
        QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlags flags=iface.flags();
        if(flags&QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlag::IsLoopBack){
            continue;
        }
        if(flags&QNetworkInterface::InterfaceFlag::IsPointToPoint){
            continue;
        }
// Filter on other properties you want here
    }
```

Comment: I 'am curious to know there is no such a direct feature in cpp?

Comment: That is correct Nidhin. In C++ you can use many abstractions such as streams, but there are no "native" way in C++ to enumerate and/or get information about network hardware. The reason is that C++ can be used on a lot of different hardware, some of which does not have "conventional" network paradigms.

Comment: tank you, but i want C++ not QT,

Comment: A. 001 Then you must look at the respective source code of such libraries as Qt and see for yourself how the accomplished the task for each platform that you are inrerested in.